# Form Collection in MVC returns concatenated old value with new value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a table set up in my view which contains text boxes that are editable. I have 2 on the UI and receive no problems before with the post back only sending back the new value. Now I have added a third text box to this list, and when the form come back, it always contains the new value with the old value.

For example I have a percentage in one of the text boxes. Before if i change the percentage from 100 to 50 in my controller I would have a value of 50 ... now the controller for that form key gets back 50,100.

Can anyone please shed some light on this issue? It was working perfectly well until I added this third text box. Each text box has a unique name that is comprised of unique keys in the table. (ie gname,dname,url could be a key and dname,gname,url is another key for a different textbox).

Answer (score 0):

Usaully if elements have the same name they will be returned with multiple values. I would double check the names and ids on the elements.

Comment: hello Mark, this is not the case as every entry put in the table is unique, hence the name for each form entry is unique as well. Also this happens for every single entry and that would mean the every single entry has a duplicate. Also another thing to note is it returns the new value and old value in a comma deliminated format.

Comment: Its certianly sounds like an odd issue, is there any jQuery or javascript building the form?

Comment: I am using the html helper provided by MVC and then I am using telerik control to create the table (I think telerik may use some javascript) ... but the odd thing is that it returned only one value until i added another text box to the grid. After that it all of a sudden returned the old and new concatenated together. :S

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the control which is showing double value ,have written only once in the from or HTML page.
Because, it solved my issue.